# About the stress generated inside an object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, stress-strain

[image]

Case 1 is the case where the external force F acts on a point of an object passing through the center of mass, and Case 2 is the case where the external force F acts evenly on the surface.

In both cases, the center of mass will move at the same acceleration.

What I'm curious about is the stress that occurs inside an object (especially does shearing force occur)?

In the case of CASE2, I don't think shear force will be generated intuitively. In the case of CASE1, I think the shear force will be generated by inertia at the part away from the point of action of the force, is my guess correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you're right. Just suppose that the top and bottom layers of your cuboid were only very weakly attached to the central part. They'd be left behind when the force is applied to the central part!